# Divisão de registros listados em Lotes PHP

Tags: php

Tenho uma listagem com 37 itens, retornando em forma de array do banco de dados na seguinte forma:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id = '5';
```

Nesta listagem, eu tenho um dividendo:

```
$total = 37; // quantidade retornada do banco de dados
$dividir = 2; // quantidade que eu desejo dividir 
$resultado = floor($total/$dividir); // arredondo para baixo
```

O total do resultado será 18. Sobram então 1 item.

O que eu preciso é inserir estes dados no banco de dados na seguinte forma:

```
INSERT INTO tabela2 (total, lote, campo1, campo2)
```

O que representa: total = 37, lote = 1 (eu dividi por 2, então os primeiros 18 registros serão com lote 1) e os demais campos

```
INSERT INTO tabela2 (total, lote, campo1, campo2)
```

O que representa: total = 37, lote = 2 (eu dividi por 2, então os outros 18 registros serão com lote 2) e os demais campos

E por fim, como sobrou um, eu preciso inserir como um terceiro lote

```
INSERT INTO tabela2 (total, lote, campo1, campo2)
```

O que representa: total = 37, lote = 3 (eu dividi por 2, então o que sobrou será o lote 3) e os demais campos

Como eu faria para que eu consiga inserir corretamente no banco de dados? Minha dúvida se resume apenas a divisão dos registros em lotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifiquei o código, veja se atende melhor:

```
<?php
$registros = [];
for($j = 0; $j < 51; $j++){
    $registros[$j] = "Registro " . $j;
}   

$total = count($registros);
$dividir = 10;
$resultado = floor($total/$dividir);
$totalLotes = $dividir + ($total % $dividir > 0 ? 1 : 0);

echo "Total por lote: $resultado. <br />";
echo "Total de lotes:  {$totalLotes}.<br />";

$lote = 1;
$contador = 0;
foreach($registros as $chave => $registro){
    if($contador == $resultado){
        $contador = 0;
        $lote++;
    }
    $contador++;

    echo "INSERT INTO tabela2 ({$total}, {$lote}, {$registro}, {$chave})" . "<br />";

}

?>
```

Comment: É quase isso, mas ele não retorna o que seria preciso, os lotes não batem, preciso inserir cada um no seu lote... mais é por ai, me disseram que posso usar como efeito de paginação, e vai inserindo conforme as paginas, usando o for, mas não consegui fazer.

Comment: @AndréBaill, modifiquei o código. Dá uma olhada.